# Как отключить автоматическое закрытие окна залипания клавиш в Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

После пяти нажатий на левый Shift открывается окно об описании функции залипания клавиш. Если это самое окно не было закрыто вручную на протяжении 5-ти минут - оно закрывается.
Необходимо отключить автоматическое закрытие, чтобы окно залипания клавиш было открыто постоянно.

Comment: Может кто-то может подсказать куда копать. Какой файл нужно изучать для решения проблемы. Также будет полезным хотя бы примерное местоположение, где прописана функция автозакрытия окна.
Буду очень рад.